# Template Missing Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have 3 models one

```
Customer               Book                 Book_Managers
id                     id                   id
first                  description          customer_id
last                   book_manager_id      visible
email                   
password
```

When the customer goes at customer#edit it then render the form books and book_managers into one form

In my bookController I have the following to create a book and book_manager

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
    def create
        @customer = current_customer
        @book = @customer.book_managers.build(:visible => "true")
        @book = @customer.book_managers.first.books.build(:description => "2012")
    end
end
```

But then it tell me there is missing template. I am also only using a simple form_for. What i am doing wrong? I believe I should be using accepts_nested_attributes_for but any one has a good tutorial for this??

Update: In regard to the railcasts here my relationship and see if it make sense?

```
Customer
    has_many :book_managers
        has_many :books, :through => :book_managers
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :book_manager
Book
    belongs_to :book_manager
    def customer
        book_manager.customer
    end
Book_Manager
    belongs_to :customer
    has_many :books
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :book
```

Comment: Missing Template error comes when it doesn't finds a view part.Need more info ... After saving book info...where should it go? ...Does the data get stored in 3 tables ?

Comment: The data get stored into 2 table, book for the description and book_manager to know if its visible or not

Comment: So After Saving you are not redirecting to any view... thats the issue... add redirect_to :action => index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, most of the time, after a successful create, you should `redirect_to` your edit or listing page with a success message (`flash[:info] = "Success"`).

So you should have

```
def create
    @customer = current_customer
    @book = @customer.book_managers.build(:visible => "true")
    @book = @customer.book_managers.first.books.build(:description => "2012")
    flash[:info] = "Success"
    redirect_to :some_action
end
```

And in the view display `<%= flash[:info] %>` in green for example :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at these railscasts http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1 and http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2. They will show you the way to correctly implement nested forms.

Comment: The problem i have with his is that he only goes down to a 2 model, is it the same for a 3 model deep?